# UWP C# / XAML Slider Value doesn't honor bound backing property

Tags: c#, xaml, slider, uwp

I've run into an issue where the Slider control value isn't honor the value of the backing property to which it's bound.  Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

XAML Code:

```
<Slider x:Name="DefenseSlider" Width="220" StepFrequency="1"
                            Minimum="0"
                            Maximum="10"
                            Value="{Binding CharacterDefense, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

C# backing code:

```
        public int CharacterDefense
    {
        get { return NewCharacter.CharacterDefense; }
        set
        {
            CalculateCharacterPointsRemaining();
            if (value <= CharacterPointsAvailable)
            {
                NewCharacter.CharacterDefense = value;
            }
            if (value > CharacterPointsAvailable)
            {
                NewCharacter.CharacterDefense = CharacterPointsAvailable;
            }


            CalculateCharacterPointsRemaining();
        }
    }
```

If it's a bug, does anyone know of a workaround, to ensure the value of the slider can go no higher than the backing value?

Regards...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the binding to be aware of `CharacterDefense` property changes, you need to raise the `PropertyChanged` event of `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

```
set
{
    CalculateCharacterPointsRemaining();
    if (value <= CharacterPointsAvailable)
    {
        NewCharacter.CharacterDefense = value;
    }
    if (value > CharacterPointsAvailable)
    {
        NewCharacter.CharacterDefense = CharacterPointsAvailable;
    }
    CalculateCharacterPointsRemaining();
    OnPropertyChanged();
}
```

However, the binding ignores the event if it is raised in the property setter call that was triggered by the binding itself. To make it work, you will need to send the event to the end of the dispatcher queue:

```
set
{
    CalculateCharacterPointsRemaining();
    if (value <= CharacterPointsAvailable)
    {
        NewCharacter.CharacterDefense = value;
    }
    if (value > CharacterPointsAvailable)
    {
        NewCharacter.CharacterDefense = CharacterPointsAvailable;
    }
    CalculateCharacterPointsRemaining();
    Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => 
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CharacterDefense)));
}
```

`Dispatcher` is a property of the `Page` class and you won't have access to it in the view model, unless you pass it from the view. While you could do that, **it is generally a bad idea**.

`Slider` control has `Maximum` property for a reason. If you want to limit the allowed range of values dynamically, you should add a view model property that returns `CharacterPointsAvailable`. Of course, whenever this value changes, you will need to `RaisePropertyChanged` to notify the binding that it should update the value:

```
public int MaxCharacterDefense
{
    get { return CharacterPointsAvailable; }
}

private void CharacterPointsAvailable()
{
    // ... existing method logic
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MaxCharacterDefense));
}
```

You can now bind your slider to this property:

```
<Slider x:Name="DefenseSlider" Width="220" StepFrequency="1"
    Minimum="0"
    Maximum="{Binding MaxCharacterDefense}"
    Value="{Binding CharacterDefense, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

The control now won't allow *invalid* values any more, so you could simplify the `CharacterDefense` setter:

```
set
{
    NewCharacter.CharacterDefense = value;
    CalculateCharacterPointsRemaining();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation.  I set the maximum value before, but ran into some challenges that would require creating another backing property, that would combine the amount of current points plus the available, which I was loathe to do.  But, your answer now saves me the time of continuing to use the setter for the value binding. Thank you. One question, if I may bother you further...why it's generally a bad idea to pass the dispatcher into the VM?

Comment: @RAB Passing the dispatcher to the view model makes unit testing of view models more difficult, and creates a dependency on the particular dispatcher implementation, limiting the portability of your code to other platforms. You could alleviate both issues by wrapping access to the dispatcher in a service interface that could have a different implementation on each platform, and a separate one without a real dispatcher for unit testing. Still, it will increase the complexity of your code, so I would avoid it if possible.

Comment: Allow me to thank you again.  There were some complications, because the OnPropertyChanged was firing values off prematurely, so I placed them all inside of their own screen update method and resolved the problem.  Your answers were most helpful!